# Does focusing on a certain part of the body increase electrical activity in that region?

Tags: physiology, neurophysiology

I am batting around ideas for master's thesis topics and was wondering whether or not just focusing on an area of the body would cause of boost of  neuronic activity? Not sure whether this would fall under the rubric of a self-fulfilling prophecy of the mind, or some other secondary body function. I though it might be interesting to examine the relative differences between varying parts of the body and their respective degrees of responsiveness to intentional cortical activity, as directed by a person. If anyone has an answer please respond soon as I can't quite nail down how to search for a question like this online (finding specific phrases, etc.) Also, feel free top point me to any readings related to this (would-be) phenom.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Gut reaction, I don't think this is a solid thesis idea. If you attach an [EMG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromyography) to my finger, and then I concentrate on my finger, and then my finger moves (due to stray thoughts), there will of course be a whole bunch of action potentials firing. However, that's kind of trivial and not really that interesting.

If your theme is "weird EM effects in the human body", one possible decent idea (and one that's gotten some quantity of buzz in the recent past) would be to focus on the role of [electric fields](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature04925) in [wound healing](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1517/14712598.2016.1098615?journalCode=iebt20). You could even add in an intentionality/focus angle, if you really wanted to.